# InputField does not always update continuously with ContinuousAction

Tags: dynamic, inputfield

By fiddling with [Vitaliy's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5725/89) for a small GUI, I've come accross this particular behaviour of `InputField`:

```
y = Null;
{InputField[Dynamic[y], String, ContinuousAction -> True],
 InputField[Dynamic[y], Boxes, ContinuousAction -> True],
 InputField[Dynamic[y], Expression, ContinuousAction -> True],
 Dynamic@y}
```

While the first two fields update correctly as the user interacts with them (updating withouth hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> or clicking outside of the `InputField`), the third one does not.

Furthermore:

```
y = Null; x = False;
Column@{
  InputField[Dynamic[y, (y = #; x = (# === "123")) &], String, ContinuousAction -> True],
  InputField[Dynamic[y, (y = #; x = (# === 123)) &], Boxes, ContinuousAction -> True],
  Dynamic@x
  }
```

Typing `123` into the first field immediately yields `True`, but the same action with the second field does not work.

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: As to the "furthermore" issue, it seems what you write of type Boxes is interpreted as a string, which is actually what happens if you do `MakeBoxes[123]`. So in the second example you should put 123 as a string too I think

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a bug, and is in fact, the expected behaviour (at least, I expect it). Look at it this way — when you input a `String` or a `Number`, Mathematica doesn't need to interpret it/evaluate it and can readily display the value dynamically.

On the other hand, with an `Expression`, it needs to know that you have finished entering the expression and it can be evaluated now. Consider what would've happened if this were not the case (each uncommented line below is a successive keystroke in in the `InputField`, and the commented lines the expected (pseudo)output if it were evaluated upon each keystroke as you expect in the question):

```
I
(* error *)
In
(* error *)
...
Integrate[
(* error *)
...
Integrate[x,x]
(* x^2 / 2 *)
```

You can see that this would be a pretty annoying behaviour.

---

It is possible to build something that evaluates expressions as they are typed. For example:

```
y = Null; x = False;
Column@{InputField[
   Dynamic[y, (y = #; x = (FullSimplify[Quiet@ToExpression[#] === 2/3 z^3])) &], String, 
   ContinuousAction -> True], Dynamic@x}
```

and the result:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

> #### Warning:
>
> Anything with `ToExpression` is potentially dangerous, as arbitrary expressions can be injected into your application and they could be malicious. It might be fine to use this approach if you're the only person using it, but if it's for external use, you should whitelist a certain set of allowed functions and reject the input if it contains anything outside that list (note: *whitelist*, not *blacklist*).

That being said, here's an example of how you could whitelist only certain heads and functions and check the input against that and evaluate only if it is "safe".

```
ClearAll[checkInput]
SetAttributes[checkInput, HoldAll]
checkInput[expr_, allowed_] := 
    Module[{inert = ToExpression[expr, StandardForm, Hold], input},    
        input = Rest@Level[inert, {-1}, Heads -> True] /. 
            x_?(AtomQ[#] && (Head[#] =!= Symbol) &) :> Head[x];

        If[Complement[input, allowed] === {}, ToExpression[expr], False]
    ]
```

Let's try it:

```
whitelisted = {Power, Times, z, Integer};
checkInput["2/3 z^3", whitelisted]
(* (2 z^3)/3 *)

checkInput["2/3 z^3 + Sin[z]", whitelisted]
(* False *)

checkInput["Import[\"!rm -rf --no-preserve-root / \",\"Text\"]", whitelisted]
(* False *)
```

You don't have to try that last one if you're worried, but rest assured, it won't evaluate. The example was to illustrate what *could* potentially be done if you didn't sanitize your input.

To use this in the example above, replace the `Quiet@ToExpression[...]` line above with `Quiet@checkInput[#, {Power, Integer, Times, z}]` and modify as needed.

Comment: That makes sense, expected something like this, thanks. But then how to check whether a more complex input expression matches the answer? Like the typesetting in [Vitaliy's example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5725/89).

Comment: I didn't understand your comment (or what specifically you were referring to in Vitaliy's answer)

Comment: Let me clarify myself then: Is it possible to build an `InputField` that continuously (during typing) tests whether the typed input is the same as a complex 2D typeset expression, e.g. `2/3 z^3`?

Comment: @IstvánZachar Please see my edit above.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks R.M.!

Comment: Somehow I missed this question and your answer completely. +1. Good warning about code injection.