# How can I change InputField value dynamically

Tags: dynamic, inputfield

I am storing the values from xlData to the result in a `Grid` form. I want when I change any of the value in any of the `InputFields`, it should show the change dynamically when I evaluate result again. I have to use this result variable again in my code. How can I do this?

```
   result = {};   
   xlData = {{1, "a", "b", "c"}, {2, "d", "e", "f"}};
   For[i = 1, i <= Length[xlData], i++,
    (iniRow = {};
     For[j = 1, j <= Length[xlData[[i]]], j++,
      If[xlData[[i, j]] != "",     
      (iniRow =Append[iniRow,InputField[xlData[[i, j]], FieldSize -> {4, 1}]];
      )]];                    
        result = Append[result, iniRow];)]
       Grid[result]
```

Comment: I'm not near mma to try it out, but please see if it is similar to this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5731/5

Comment: @b.gatessucks: Yes, I have edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code can be made much simpler as such...

```
xlData = {{1, "a", "b", "c"}, {2, "d", "e", "f"}};
Grid@Table[
   With[{i = i, j = j}, 
   InputField[Dynamic[xlData[[i, j]]], FieldSize -> {4, 1}]], {i, 1, Length[xlData]},
   {j,1,Length[xlData[[1]]]}]
```

As you change values, it can be monitored by:

```
Dynamic[xlData]
```

As written, the code keeps xlData with a `List` head at all times.