# "Masking" an InputField

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

In building an assignment for my class, I would like set up an `InputField`, where they will enter a function.  I was wondering if there was a way to "continuously" check if their function is being defined correctly (the thing is, they often forget the underscore after the variables as in `f[x_]`, they use ( ) instead of [ ], etc.).

I am imagining some red "X" that becomes a green checkmark when the beginning of the definition is correctly written (similar to the way some websites show you if you've re-entered your password correctly when signing up for an account).

If this seems too complicated, I would even be interested in seeing how to mask something simpler, like perhaps a phone number.

Is this possible in Mathematica?

Thanks!

Comment: Mathematica is quite difficult to parse "continuously". Think for example in this (convoluted) way of defining a function. `(With[{# = f[x_]}, argtra := Sin[x]]) &@argtra`

Comment: In [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5733/5), I show a way to create an input field that evaluates continuously and displays the result (True/False) for each key stroke. You can modify that to your needs and make it a red X and a green check instead of T/F.

Comment: @rm-rf: While I like halirutan's solution below, your answer linked above is very cool, and I will definitely be using it as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I want to give an answer using `SyntaxQ` and `SyntaxLength`. `SyntaxQ` takes a string and returns `True`, when the string has correct Mathematica syntax. On the other hand `SyntaxLength` returns an integer which shows up to what character the string is correct syntax. If the integer is larger than the length of the input string it indicates, that more input is needed. The following function uses this to create a colored `Style`-text showing where errors occur, whether more input is needed or whether the string is correct syntax:

```
parseString[str_String] := 
  With[{l = SyntaxLength[str], t = SyntaxQ[str], 
    len = StringLength[str]},
   Which[
    t,
    Style[str, 14, Darker[Green]],
    l > len,
    Row[{Style[str, 14], Style["_", 14, Red]}],
    True,
    Row[{Style[StringTake[str, Min[l, StringLength[str]]], 14], 
      Style[StringDrop[str, Min[l, StringLength[str]]], 14, Red]}]
    ]
   ];
parseString[__] := "";
```

Now I use this to continuously check an input field

```
Panel[Column@{InputField[Dynamic[str], String, 
    ContinuousAction -> True], Dynamic[parseString[str]]}]
```

### Test cases

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow, this is great!

Comment: @Steve, thanks.

Comment: @halirutan. I, too, think this is a great answer, but I think it's a little misleading to say your function "creates a colored string" since it returns either a `Style` object or a `Row` object containing `Style` objects. These are objects that *Mathematica displays* as styled text. I think it is useful to make this distinction because in the past I got myself into trouble thinking I could treat `Style` objects as strings.

Comment: @m_goldberg I fixed it. Hopefully the people using this see that it's not *one* `Style` but a `Row`.. Btw, I never mind if someone improves my text!