# Having three Control Objects for the same Dynamic variable which can override eachother

Tags: dynamic, inputfield, slider, popup

I'm creating an application with Dynamics for calculating and plotting circular orbits.

It allows the user to set a custom radius, giving them an option to either use an InputField as well as a Slider to emulate the Slider ability from the Manipulate but as part of the User Interface. The application also includes a selection of preset orbits with fixed values accessible via a Popup menu.

I'm currently having an issue setting up the 3 Control objects (Popup menu, InputField, Slider) such that they reflect the set value but are also able to be independently edited in order to override the other selections.

[image: Control object setup]

For example, when I select *Geostationary* in the Popup menu, I want to set the *radius* variable to the preset value for the Geostationary orbit and I want this value to be updated and shown both on the Slider and the InputField.
However, I also want to be able to either alter the value on the Slider or the InputField (thus setting the radius to a custom user-defined variable) and I want the Popup menu's selection to update to show the *Custom* option.
The overriding process would occur in a "first come" basis as in the last Control object to be edited is the one which overrides all the others.

As of right now I only have the Popup menu and the InputField included - when I include the Slider this locks both the InputField and the Slider to the preset value from the Popup selection and I can't alter the values through 
them, only with the Popup menu. Even then, I can select the *Custom* option in the Popup and set the value through the InputField successfully, but I haven't been able to do the reverse, that is, alter the Popup menu selection from a *non-Custom* option to the *Custom* option by changing the value in the InputField. When I select a preset option on the Popup menu it also doesn't update the value in the input field - despite it overriding the variable itself used for the calculations so the results are correct.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I apologize for the long post and for these being relatively simple concepts and when I apply each one individually (looking at the tutorials) they work, but it's combining them altogether which is causing issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note:* See also my other answer for a different approach and a discussion of the differences between the two.

You can achieve what you want by introducing a helper variable (`custom` in the code below) that tracks whether a custom value is used. This allows you to easily control the state of the `PopupMenu`. The rest can be done using the second argument of [`Dynamic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) to make the necessary changes:

```
radiusInput[Dynamic[r_], gs_, range_: {100, 2000}] := DynamicModule[
  {custom = False},
  r = gs;
  Row@{
    PopupMenu[
     Dynamic[
      custom,
      custom = #; If[! custom, r = gs]; &
      ],
     {False -> "Geostationary", True -> "Custom"}
     ],
    Slider[
     Dynamic[r, {custom = True; &, Automatic, Automatic}],
     range
     ],
    InputField[
     Dynamic[r, {custom = True; &, Automatic, Automatic}],
     Number,
     ContinuousAction -> True
     ]
    }
  ]

radiusInput[Dynamic[r], 200]
```

[image]

Note how both the [`Slider`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slider.html) and [`InputField`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputField.html) set `custom=True` when the user starts editing. For the `InputField`, we need to set the type to `Number` and `ContinuousAction->True`, as shown by @rm-rf in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5733/36508).

Comment: Thank you very much! That second answer is indeed much more elegant in its looks but I did end up going for an iteration on the first one :)

Answer (score 2):

In my other answer, I show how to achieve the desired effect using the second argument of `Dynamic` to manually do the necessary changes to the `PopupMenu`. Here is a significantly simpler approach that uses the default label of [`PopupMenu`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PopupMenu.html) to get the desired effect:

```
radiusInput2[r_, gs_, range_: {100, 2000}] :=
 Row@{
   PopupMenu[
    r,
    {gs -> "Geostationary"},
    "Custom"
    ],
   Slider[
    r,
    range
    ],
   InputField[
    r,
    Number,
    ContinuousAction -> True
    ]
   }

radiusInput2[Dynamic[r2], 200]
```

[image]

As can be seen, the behavior is quite similar to the other one. Some notable differences:

- You can't manually set the `PopupMenu` to "Custom" (which is not necessarily a bad thing)
- When you enter the exact value of the "Geostationary" setting, the `PopupMenu` will change to "Geostationary". Again, might even be desirable
- You can supply a custom second argument to the `Dynamic` passed to the function, which could allow for more customization. (In the other example, this would only be possible with way more effort, since we're already using custom functions there)
- The other approach allows for more customization of the behavior (by adding more stuff to the functions handling the value changes), which might be hard to implement with this approach