# Generating multiple choice questions with a random list of operations and rational numbers

Tags: interface, education

**Edit: Necesito que Mathematica me genere al azar una lista de operaciones (+,-,*,:) con numeros racionales .
La cantidad de elementos de la lista asi como la dificultad de los racionales queda determinado mi.
Las respuestas correctas se almacenan y se imprimen al final del test.
Los ejemplos que me han dado mas abajo para la presentacion por pantalla estan muy bien , pero yo deseo imprimir la pantalla y multicopiarla en papel despues .**
Algo parecido a lo  que sale en este link, en la segunda respuesta (lo encontre recien)

[Writing a simple application: interactive quiz for multiplication table practice](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44979/writing-a-simple-application-interactive-quiz-for-multiplication-table-practice?lq=1)

, pero con racionales, y no solo con la  multiplicación , también con la suma , la resta  y la  división, las alternativas hacia  el lado , no para abajo , la idea es imprimir lo que sale en la pantalla y pasarlo a papel

**I need you to Mathematica generates a list of random operations (+, -, *, :) with rational numbers.
The number of items in the list as well as the difficulty of rational is determined me.
The correct answers are stored and printed at the end of the test.
The examples I have given below for the presentation on screen are fine, but I want to print the screen and copy paper after**

Something like what goes on this link, the second response (I found recently)

[Writing a simple application: interactive quiz for multiplication table practice](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44979/writing-a-simple-application-interactive-quiz-for-multiplication-table-practice?lq=1)

But with rational, and not just with multiplication, also with addition, subtraction and division, alternatives to the side, not down, the idea is to print what's on the screen and pass it on to paper

translated by google

(I would like to generate a simple multiple-choice test interface where students can click on candidate answers, for instance:)

```
01) The value of 2/3 + 5/4 =
a) 1/3 b) 4/5 c) 4/9 d) 8/7 e) 6/5

02) The value of 4/6 * 5/9 =
a) 20/54 b) 13/8 c) 1/2 d) 9/4 e) 7/13
```

etc.

Comment: I am sorry, but I simply cannot understand this question.  If English is not your native language consider editing the question to *include* a version in your native language with the hope that someone can translate it for you.

Comment: We will be able find a cheap translator for you either from Spanish or Portuguese

Comment: Related: [Automatically check student answers in tests](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5721/245)

Answer (score 4):

```
Framed[
   Column[
     {Text[Style["1/3+1/6 =", Italic, 14]], 
     RadioButtonBar[Null, {"a) 3/2", "b) 1/2", "c) 2/3", "d) 7/9", "e) 11/4" }]}
         ]
       ]
```

[image]

Or a longer version:

```
 Framed[
 Column[
  {Text[Style["1)    1/3+1/6 =", Italic, 14]], 
   RadioButtonBar[
    Null, {"a) 3/2", "b) 1/2", "c) 2/3", "d) 7/9", "e) 11/4"}],
   Text[Style["2)    2/3 * 1/9 =", Italic, 14]], 
   RadioButtonBar[
    Null, {"a) 3/2", "b) 1/2", "c) 2/3", "d) 7/9", "e) 11/4"}],
   Text[Style["3)    2/9 - 1/12 =", Italic, 14]], 
   RadioButtonBar[
    Null, {"a) 3/2", "b) 1/2", "c) 2/3", "d) 7/9", "e) 11/4"}]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image]