# How can I evaluate untrusted Mathematica code in a sandbox?

Tags: kernel, contexts, security

Is there any way to build a sandbox to evaluate untrusted *Mathematica* expressions in order to prevent them from having (malicious or accidental) harmful side effects?

Context: I'm developing a system wherein students will enter code into designated notebook cells, and my package will extract the code, evaluate it, and offer feedback. The problem is, even if I evaluate their code within a separate context (and I'm having trouble making that happen), they could still use explicit contexts to affect a different context, invoke `Quit`, or use filesystem manipulation functions to mess with my computer.

It seems to me that there are two aspects to this problem: isolating execution of their code from everything else the kernel is doing (like running my package), and isolating their code from everything on my computer external to *Mathematica*. The first might be accomplished by using a separate kernel (somehow), but I have no ideas for the second.

Wolfram must have addressed this problem while developing WebMathematica, right?

Comment: You could protect your _machine_ (files, OS, etc) by sandboxing the whole Mathematica execution. As for sandboxing code "inside" Mathematica ... there are so many ways to circumvent protections that I think you will end up trying to build a CDF environment yourself

Comment: As a follow-up to belisarius' comment: try the program [sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/). It won't help against Quit but it will prevent your computer from being messed up by the code. Related: [list-of-dangerous-functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29364/list-of-dangerous-functions).

Comment: You could also run it on Linux in VirtualBox (free).  It might be overkill though. Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249063/run-an-untrusted-c-program-in-a-sandbox-in-linux-that-prevents-it-from-opening-f

Comment: Somewhat related: [Automatically check student answers in tests](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5721/245)

Comment: Alas, I'm looking for something I can do entirely within *Mathematica*. This is for a package that students can run to self-test their code, as well as that I can run to check the students' code. (In concept, it's a little like a unit testing suite, though with the tests written by an authority other than the programmer.)

Comment: The package located at `FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "Applications", "Security"}` may be of interest (@Szabolcs).

Comment: Also related: [(29779)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29779/121)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should consider using the sandbox functionality. You can create a subkernel and put it in sandbox mode this way:

```
link = LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine]<> " -wstp -noicon"];
LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[Developer`StartProtectedMode[]]];
```

You can then interact with this subkernel using the standard `LinkWrite` and `LinkRead` functions. If you don't mind your master kernel being sandboxed, you can even just evaluate `` Developer`StartProtectedMode[] `` there, but it disables a lot of functionality (mostly import/export and file system manipulation).

Note that sandbox mode also will only allow you to load `.m`/`.wl` files from very specific directories. You can set this in the call itself as well:

```
Developer`StartProtectedMode[{"Read" -> {$myPath}, "Write" -> {$myPath}, "Execute" -> {$myPath}}]
```

where `$myPath` is the path to where you store the code you wish to interact with.

Comment: @Szabolcs Incidentally, this is part of the security features of CDF Player, FreeCDF files are always executed in sandbox mode.

Comment: Whoa, this might be exactly what I was hoping for. The help pages and guide seem thin, though. Is there any additional documentation available?

Comment: @ibeatty As far as I know, the ``Developer`StartProtectedMode`` and related functions are undocumented. For information on `LinkRead` and `LinkWrite`, check out `tutorial/CallingSubsidiaryWolframSystemProcesses`

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to use this as follows. Assuming you have configured multiple kernels, put the one you want in protected mode by evaluation ``Developer`StartProtectedMode[]``, call it `"SafeKernel"`. Next open the notebook with ``NotebookOpen["~/Desktop/UnsafeNotebook.nb", Evaluator -> "SafeKernel"]``. Not sure if this can be abused, but it is better than the alternative of ``Developer`StartProtectedMode[]`` inside a dangerous notebook, as the notebook can have special rules for what is actually evaluated.

Answer (score 16):

I have been solving exactly the same problem about 2 years ago (http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/125587?p_p_auth=aZGMz5bs). Students are uploading piece of Mathematica (Wolfram Language) code which is run by a testing script (in Mathematica) and the results are compared with a reference solution.

To prevent the students to run potentially dangerous code I am using this initialization part (maybe I have missed some functions):

```
ClearAttributes[{Run,RunThrough,CopyFile,DeleteFile,RenameFile,CreateDirectory,CopyDirectory,DeleteDirectory,RenameDirectory,OpenRead,OpenWrite,Read,Write,BinaryRead,BinaryWrite},Protected]
Run[___]:=$Failed;
RunThrough[___]:=$Failed;
CopyFile[___]:=$Failed;
DeleteFile[___]:=$Failed;
RenameFile[___]:=$Failed;
CreateDirectory[___]:=$Failed;
CopyDirectory[___]:=$Failed;
DeleteDirectory[___]:=$Failed;
RenameDirectory[___]:=$Failed;
OpenRead[___]:=$Failed;
OpenWrite[___]:=$Failed;
Read[___]:=$Failed;
Write[___]:=$Failed;
BinaryRead[___]:=$Failed;
BinaryWrite[___]:=$Failed;
SetAttributes[{Run,RunThrough,CopyFile,DeleteFile,RenameFile,CreateDirectory,CopyDirectory,DeleteDirectory,RenameDirectory,OpenRead,OpenWrite,Read,Write,BinaryRead,BinaryWrite},Protected]
```

To detect if the testing script finished correctly I am using predefined exit code (different than the default 0). Example:

```
Exit[123 (* some secret code *)]
```

This code is tested from the "top-level" bash script which runs the Mathematica.
If the student uses `Quit` command in his solution, it will skip my `Exit` with exit code and the whole test will fail.

An example how to run the testing script and test the results (exit codes):

```
timeout -s 9 10 math -noprompt -run < ./tester.wl >./results.txt
RET=$?

# use the same "secret code"
if [ $RET -eq 123 ]
then
# OK
fi

if [ $RET -eq 137 ]
then
# TIMEOUT
fi
```

I am using the timeout command, because the `TimeConstrained` function in Mathematica worked unreliably.

Comment: I wonder if the security features the CDF player uses can be enabled in any way.  There's more than these functions that can be used for harm, though I don't know which ones of those use one of these internally.

Comment: This approach could work, but I share Szabolc's nervousness that it won't eliminate *all* possible dangers. But perhaps that's just not possible here.

Comment: @Szabolcs there is a list of dangerous functions that are stored in an internal text file. I don't have the reference handy right now but have posted it on here before(maybe 2-3 years ago). Presumably if you were able to find this file in the CDF directory and modify it you could enable some functions that are otherwise prevented. ...but I have never tried to do that

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Your answer to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29364/list-of-dangerous-functions)? -- Zdenek, have you also consider setting the attribute [`Locked`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Locked.html), too?

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes, thanks for linking to it

Answer (score 3):

i am doing the same thing as you did，and i am using MSP module which is a security solution for webMathmatica。please refer my topic [How to adapt MSPToExpression function in $PrePrint?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100596/how-to-adapt-msptoexpression-function-in-preprint)

sandbox seems another good solution for security，mathematica online is using it。
can i ask whether you solved this by using sandbox？

Comment: Sorry to be slow in replying… Missed the question earlier. Yes, running a second kernel in sandbox mode solved my problem, although it has been incredibly difficult and error-prone, primarily because of the difficulty of constructing and sending expressions to the sandbox properly wrapped in Hold or Unevaluated or the like, without accidentally evaluating *something* too early, and yet getting the variables I *want* to be replaced properly replaced. Basically, it's a huge PITA, but… it works. Eventually. With a little black magic.

Comment: @ibeatty congratulation! and I solved this as well by using MSP module. but I think sandbox should be more security. Will take a investigation on that.