# How to adapt MSPToExpression function in $PrePrint?

Tags: evaluation, symbols, webmathematica, security

I am introducing the mathematica [Security](http://reference.wolfram.com/webMathematica/tutorial/AdvancedTopicsSecurity.html) (MSP module) to our system. The [Document](http://reference.wolfram.com/webMathematica/ref/MSPToExpression.html) suggests use `MSPToExpression` as followed:

```
Needs["MSP`"]

SetSecurity[];

$$var = "5+7";

MSPToExpression[ $$var] (*the output is 12*)
```

---

But when I tried to adapt this function to `$PrePrint` with scripts:

```
$PrePrint = With[{$$var = ToString[#, InputForm]}, MSPToExpression[$$var]] &;
(*or*)

$PrePrint = With[{expr = #}, MSPToExpression[expr]] &;
(*or*)

$PrePrint = With[{$$var = #}, MSPToExpression[$$var]] &;
```

Input: `5+7`

there's same error says:
[image]

It can't recognize `$$var` as symbol, can anyone help me on this? Many thanks! :)

Comment: What if you use `Module`? `With` injects expressions to held slots.

Comment: @Kuba Hi, Could you please paste the full script ? I am a real newbee for mathematica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose this is what you need.

So the first thing is to use `Module` since `With` injects values into held expressions.

Moreover `PrePrint` is probably to late to catch `"5+7"`. So I'd go with `$Pre`:

```
$Pre = Function[expr, 
  Module[
        {expr$ = ToString[Unevaluated[expr], InputForm]},
         MSPToExpression[expr$]
  ],
  HoldAllComplete
]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well. it's what I was looking for .

Comment: Watch out when using `HoldAll` instead of `HoldAllComplete` in such functions! `Evaluate[5 + 7]` then evaluates to `MSPToExpression["12"]`

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom good point.